# How merge master with newBranch, without loss deleted directory on newBranch

Tags: git, git-merge

1. did `git checkout -b newBranch` from `master`
2. on `newBranch` delete some redundant directory but needed on `master`
3. pushing some commits on `newBranch`
4. then have to merge `master` with `newBranch`

**problem:**

when `git merge newBranch` from `master`, in `master` the necessary directory is deleted, which was deleted on `newBranch`. (I was counting on a conflict)

on the other side when `git merge master` from `newBranch` the deleted directory not adds again.

**task:**

merge `master` with `newBranch`, with saving deleted on `newBranch` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with hard copy/past the previously deleted directory from newBranch.

1. copy deleted directory on the master
2. paste it on the newBranch
3. make commit on the newBranch
4. checkout to master
5. merge master with newBranch

thats all.